# Codeigniter site replicated in subdirectory not displaying individual pages

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url, redirect, subdirectory

We have just copied a Codeigniter website (from our root domain) to a subdirectory on the same root domain (with all config.php changes made and a new database etc.). However, page links don't display the individual pages yet the browser simply reloads the index.php page content (as if it's loading a new page) and changes the URL in the browser window to the correct page.

This is really odd and I've spent hours pouring over it, so I'm hoping someone here may be able to give me a starting search point.

For your information, the .htaccess in the subdirectory is:

`RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^test.php$ mod_rewrite.php

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Have you copied the .htaccess? remember its hidden

Comment: Yes, it's entirely the same - I have edited my original post with its contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now sorted after a lot of different attempts!

File `config.php` in **root -> application -> config** (line 46) was originally:
`$config['uri_protocol'] = ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1') ? 'AUTO' : 'ORIG_PATH_INFO';`

It should be:
`$config['uri_protocol'] = ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1') ? 'AUTO' : 'PATH_INFO';`

All's now functioning correctly.

Answer (score 0):

if theres a new codeigniter install in a subdirectory now that used to be on the root, you need to include the name of the sub directory in front of the index.php parts of your htaccess

something like this(the change is on the last line):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^$ /dev/index.php [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|zip\.php|resources)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dev/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

dev should be changed to the name of your subdirectory.  also, if neither or these works and you have a htaccess on your root, it could be effecting this subdirectory.

Comment: No change sadly despite clearing the cache, having our site in development mode on Cloudflare and starting a new browser session with a cleared cache. This is so odd. The page URL changes to what it should in the browser URL bar, but the content remains simply as the index file.

Comment: hmm.  now that I look closer, what is that test.php part there for? I'm editing my answer to include a standard re-write rule set that works for me.  you could try that. yours is a little hard for me to read without line breaks.

Comment: It wouldn't let me added the line breaks for some reason on here. <edit - I've managed to find out how, see the first post>. The test.php is a simple file to detect if mod_rewrite is actually running... which it is.

Comment: yeah, pasting code is annoying sometimes when its multiple line.  its easier to just write in the code tag yourself rather than using ctrl+k

Comment: The .htaccess file is the same on two other installations from a while back - I really can't see what the problem is this time. Eek!